# Should the Age of Ultron be Avenged?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

Today I noticed that the tag for the MCU film *Avengers: Age of Ultron* is [age-of-ultron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-ultron).

**Considering this is not the official name of the film, should the tag be renamed to match?**

---

Other tags in the MCU Avengers series are:

- [avengers-2012](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-2012) - given the 2012 maker to distinguish from the team itself.
- [avengers-infinity-war](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-infinity-war) - newly created at the time of this post by me

My thought into creating the new tag was that 1) we should use the official name, and 2) there might be a Marvel Comic story line with the same name. This reasoning would also apply as to why the [age-of-ultron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-ultron) should be adusted in some way.

Comment: Is there any good reason to assume that people can't find the film when searching tags?

Comment: If you start by search "avengers" the tag does not appear, one could argue it is easy to make the adjustment to  just search for "age of ultron", but why not make it even easier by retagging and/or tag synonyms.

Comment: It's better to go with official name "Avengers: Age of Ultron", no point in skipping words.

Comment: It'd be an easy change for a mod to rename the tag to [tag:avengers-age-of-ultron]. But since that wouldn't be reversible by regular users, I'll wait a while in case anyone has a good reason *not* to rename it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's what i was thinking. since it is an older tag I figured I'd would "ask" instead of "stating".

Comment: Have we abandoned our goofy-titles-for-tag-related-meta-questions policy? If not, surely this one deserves a little something; maybe “Is the Age of Ultron coming to an end?”

Comment: @PaulD.Waite HAH! Yes, time for an edit. Thank you!

Comment: @Skooba: excellent! Much better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Rename it and create an 'Avengers' convention

**Step 1:**
Create a new tag called [avengers-age-of-ultron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-age-of-ultron) and either make [age-of-ultron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-ultron) a synonym (this allows people to find it) or delete it. Additionally, this can create a distinction between the movie and the comics of the [same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Ultron).

**Step 2:**
Create a tag called [avengers-2012](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-2012) so that we can make [the-avengers-2012](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-avengers-2012) a synonym and tag all existing questions with the new tag. (no one searches for '*the* Avengers').

**Step 3:**
Keep tag [avengers-infinity-war](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-infinity-war) as it is. You can create a [infinity-war](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinity-war) tag and make it a synonym, but that might cause unnecessary confusion.

**Step 4:**
Every new 'Avengers' movie should begin with 'avengers'.

Comment: **Step 5:**  
Hope that the MCU doesn't start doing some weird shit with their titles like [The Fast and the Furious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fast_and_the_Furious) did.

Comment: The synonyms seem superfluous. Type "age-of-ultron" (or "Age of Ultron", or "ageo", ...) and see what happens.

Comment: [tag:the-avengers-2012] is fine tag, official movie title had "the". rest I am agreeing with , +1

Comment: `avengers-age-of-ultron` at minimum, rest is nice extras, not entirely necessary

Comment: @Möoz After Infinity War and its sequel are done, they might go with aVengers? Cos it’s the fifth? And V is 5 in Roman numerals? And the kids love Roman numerals?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Stop it. Stop it right now.

Comment: @Möoz - Precisely my thoughts. Directors love doing weird shit with their titles. And then you end up with Star Trek *into Darkness* with no colon.